# What does the GetWindowLong(hwnd, 0) mean?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

```cpp
LRESULT WINAPI TextViewWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TextView* ptv = (TextView*)GetWindowLong(hwnd, 0);
    switch (msg)
    {
        case WM_NCCREATE:

        if ((ptv = new TextView(hwnd)) == nullptr)
            return FALSE;

        SetWindowLong(hwnd, 0, (LONG)ptv);
        return TRUE;
}
```

Code from: http://www.catch22.net/tuts/neatpad/neatpad-overview

The `TextView` here is Owner-Drawn Controls.

My question here is:

```cpp
GetWindowLong(hwnd, 0)
SetWindowLong(hwnd, 0, (LONG)ptv);
```

what does that mean? I have searched MSDN, [it says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlonga):

> The following values are also available when the `hWnd` parameter identifies a dialog box.
>
> ...
> `DWL_MSGRESULT`
> 0
>
> Retrieves the return value of a message processed in the dialog box procedure.

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the requested value.
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.

> If `SetWindowLong` has not been called previously, `GetWindowLong` returns zero for values in the extra window or class memory.

Comment: The `DWL_MSGRESULT` is needed for dialog boxes. Because dialog box
procedures return a `BOOL` value they use `SetWindowLong` with `DWL_MSGRESULT`
to set a return value if they handle a message and want to return a value. Source: https://microsoft.public.vc.language.narkive.com/fVY0Xbsh/about-setwindowlong-with-index-dwl-msgresult

Comment: You seem to have skipped over the earlier help section that explains this. *`nIndex`, Type: int. The zero-based offset to the value to be retrieved. Valid values are in the range zero through the number of bytes of extra window memory, minus four.* So this pointer is stored in that window at the offset zero. The `DWL_MSGRESULT` does not apply because it's not a dialog window. This code is also incompatible with 64-bit, and should be fixed to use `GetWindowLongPtr`.

Comment: @ Asesh So can you tell me what this function means in this code? The code is short and easy to read. I don't know what is the use of (TextView*)GetWindowLong(hwnd, 0) here.

Comment: @ffxxee Have you actually read the description of GetWindowLong and SetWindowLong that you yourself are linking to? There is an extra storage area associated with the window. The author of this code decided to put a value there, at the offset of 0. Then they retrieved it from there. I don't see what more could be said here.

Comment: @GSerg Thank you, I re-read the code, and then understand the meaning of these two functions
It should use additional memory to save the pointer to the TextView, so that the object can be manipulated with this pointer in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the `GetWindowLong()` documentation:

> nIndex
>
> Type: int
>
> The zero-based offset to the value to be retrieved. **Valid values are in the range zero through the number of bytes of extra window memory**, minus four; for example, if you specified 12 or more bytes of extra memory, a value of 8 would be an index to the third 32-bit integer.
>
> ...
>
> The following values are also available **when the hWnd parameter identifies a dialog box.**
>
> DWL_MSGRESULT
> 0
> Retrieves the return value of a message processed in the dialog box procedure.

The code in question is for a window that wraps a `TextView` object.  The window is NOT a dialog box, and there is an `InitTextView()` function beint called that registers a `WNDCLASSEX` whose `cbWndExtra` field is set to `sizeof(TextView*)` when calling `RegisterClassEx()`:

```cpp
BOOL InitTextView()
{
    WNDCLASSEX  wcx;

    //Window class for the main application parent window
    wcx.cbSize          = sizeof(wcx);
    wcx.style           = 0;
    wcx.lpfnWndProc     = TextViewWndProc; // <--
    wcx.cbClsExtra      = 0;
    wcx.cbWndExtra      = sizeof(TextView *); // <--
    wcx.hInstance       = GetModuleHandle(0);
    wcx.hIcon           = 0;
    wcx.hCursor         = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_IBEAM);
    wcx.hbrBackground   = (HBRUSH)0;        //NO FLICKERING FOR US!!
    wcx.lpszMenuName    = 0;
    wcx.lpszClassName   = TEXTVIEW_CLASS; // <-- 
    wcx.hIconSm         = 0;

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcx) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

And then there is a `CreateTextView()` function that creates a new window, and thus a new `TextView` object, using that registered class:

```cpp
HWND CreateTextView(HWND hwndParent)
{
    return CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, 
        TEXTVIEW_CLASS, _T(""), // <--
        WS_VSCROLL |WS_HSCROLL | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 
        hwndParent, 
        0, 
        GetModuleHandle(0), 
        0);
}
```

In the window's `WM_NCCREATE` handler, a new `TextView` object is created, and a pointer to that object is stored directly in the `HWND` itself, at offset 0 of the window's extra memory. Other message handlers for the same window can then retrieve that `TextView*` pointer and use the object as needed.  In this case, `WM_NCDESTROY` and `WM_PAINT` specifically:

```cpp
LRESULT WINAPI TextViewWndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    TextView *ptv = (TextView *)GetWindowLong(hwnd, 0);

    switch(msg)
    {
    // First message received by any window - make a new TextView object
    // and store pointer to it in our extra-window-bytes
    case WM_NCCREATE:

        if((ptv = new TextView(hwnd)) == 0)
            return FALSE;

        SetWindowLong(hwnd, 0, (LONG)ptv);
        return TRUE;

    // Last message received by any window - delete the TextView object
    case WM_NCDESTROY:

        delete ptv;
        return 0;

    // Draw contents of TextView whenever window needs updating
    case WM_PAINT:
        return ptv->OnPaint();

    default:
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i got cbWndExtra and cbClsExtra wrong
There is indeed  wcx.cbWndExtra = sizeof(TextView*);
 in the code